# SQL Query group by, having min, not selecting minimum value?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
select s.attr1, s.attr2
from table1 s
where s.primarykey in 
    (select g.primarykey
    from table2 g
    group by g.primarykey
    having avg(g.numattr) > 80)
group by s.attr1
having min(s.attr3)
order by (s.attr2);
```

This query is supposed to be checking average numattr > 80 in table2 then for the primary keys that meet that, for each attr1 choose the lowest with attr3 and then order them by attr2. I'm getting a result that doesn't choose the minimum value and I'm not sure why.

Comment: That is not what this query does.  The `having` clause just checks that `min(s.attr3)` is neither `0` nor `NULL`.  Your `group by` is also malformed, because there are columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `MIN` to `SELECT` to have it into the result. Also, you need to group by both `attr1` and `attr2`. Can you try the following:

```
SELECT s.attr1, s.attr2, min(s.attr3)
FROM table1 s
WHERE s.primarykey IN
    (SELECT g.primarykey
    FROM table2 g
    GROUP BY g.primarykey
    HAVING avg(g.numattr) > 80)
GROUP BY s.attr1, s.attr2
ORDER BY s.attr2;
```

Comment: I don't want min in the result, I want to filter the result based on the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.attr1, s.attr2, 
FROM table1 s
WHERE s.attr3 = 
(SELECT min(s2.attr3) from table1 s2 where s.attr1 = s2.attr1 group by s2.attr1)
and s.primarykey IN
(SELECT g.primarykey
FROM table2 g
GROUP BY g.primarykey
HAVING avg(g.numattr) > 80)
GROUP BY s.attr1, s.attr2
ORDER BY s.attr2;
```

I think this does it.